# error ReferenceError: System is not defined file:///E:/PetsDemoAj/index.html Line 17

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am new in angular JS2 and tried this sample project provided in the given link http://embed.plnkr.co/eBv3hZZSk9Tx3joykvSQ/ I have tried this example , and getting error ReferenceError: System is not defined file:///E:/PetsDemoAj/index.html Line 17,in console; PetsDemoAj is my project name. Thanks in adavance

Answer (score 0):

Its about your `systemjs.config.js` file, you need to declare 'System', because compilator doesnt recognize this, add this line upon line where `System` is called:

```
declare var System: any;
```

this should fix the problem